# gpg - gpg-preset-passphrase installation

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

Issue:
- The passphrase is repeatedly being requested when I pass `show <name of credential>`.

Doing some Googling, I found you can do that with gpg-preset-passphrase, however I'm not sure where to get it or if it included in the gpg distribution.

This is the current version of gpg I'm running.

Does anyone know how to get gpg-preset-passphrase installed?

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.22
libgcrypt 1.5.3
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ?, ?, ELG, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like it was installed but just not directly accessible through the `gpg-preset-passphrase` command, but rather: `/usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase`:

```
/usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase --version
gpg-preset-passphrase (GnuPG) 2.0.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 7):

The most compatible way is to use `gpgconf --list-dirs libexecdir`
like this:

```bash
"$(gpgconf --list-dirs libexecdir)"/gpg-preset-passphrase --present
```

I've tested this on both macOS and ubuntu 18.04, the folder is set to:

- on macOS: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.7_1/libexec`
- ubuntu:  `/usr/lib/gnupg`

Remember to use preset you need to add `allow-preset-passphrase`\to your `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`. It is useful as well to change the default 2h storage time to something larger, the agent config options are:

```
max-cache-ttl 34560000 
max-cache-ttl-ssh 34560000
```

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu 16 install it was in the `gnupg-agent` package and placed in `/usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase`.

Comment: On ubuntu 18.04.5  it is `gpg-agent` under /usr/lib/gnupg/gpg-preset-passphrase